# Ratio of cost price when profit percents are same

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How to solve this question. I find it very confusing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ratio of their cost price is $16:15$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_i,S_i$ denote the cost and sell prices for the $i^{th}$ vendor.  Let's suppose that vendor $1$ works off cost price, while vendor $2$ works off sale price.

Working with vendor $1$ we get $$\frac {S_1-C_1}{C_1}=\frac 14\implies S_1=\frac 54 C_1$$

Working with vendor $2$ we get $$\frac {S_2-C_2}{S_2}=\frac 14\implies S_2=\frac 43 C_2$$

We are told that $S_1=S_2$ from which we deduce that $$\frac 54C_1=\frac 43 C_2\implies \frac {C_1}{C_2}=\frac 43\times \frac 45=\boxed{\frac {16}{15}}$$  Note:  the information about the value of the profit differential appears to be irrelevant to the problem at hand.